# How to get colorful output in SQL Oracle without using WHEN

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Check_ein_Lager (lagernummer INT)
AS
   summe               number := 0;
   kapazitätsgränze    number;
BEGIN
   SELECT lager.stueckkap
     INTO kapazitätsgränze
     FROM lager
    WHERE lagernummer = lager.lnr;

   FOR v_rec IN (SELECT *
                   FROM lagerbuchung
                  WHERE lagerbuchung.lnr = lagernummer)
   LOOP
      summe := summe + v_rec.stueck;
     IF (summe > kapazitätsgränze)
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
            'Überfüllter Lagerstand' || ' ' || lagernummer || ' ' || summe);
      END IF;
      IF (summe < 0)
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
            'Negativer Lagerstand' || ' ' || lagernummer || ' ' || '<html><font size="5" color="red">' || summe);
      END IF;

   END LOOP;
END Check_ein_Lager;
/

execute Check_ein_Lager(13);
```

I would like to have negative numbers colored in **RED**.

Is it possible without using WHEN .... and then HTML Code.

Comment: Can you explain your question in more details.

Comment: @VBoka So my output is summe and it's an ´int´ and there are negative numbers and I want them to be in red textcolor. Is it possible to make them red in if statement or do I need special SELECT like the answer downbelow.

Comment: Even if you dbms_output.put_line with html tags, it is still up to the client to interpret it.  And given that dbms_ouput only writes to a buffer, it is up to the client to even decide to do anything with it at all.  dbms_output is good for testing/debugging, but is not the proper tool for production code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have first created two tables you have mention in your procedure(I suggest that for your next question you prepare this create statements and insert statements and put them in your question. It will be much easyer for people to help you):

```
create table lager(stueckkap int, lnr int);

insert into lager values (1, 10);
insert into lager values (2, 9);


create table lagerbuchung(lnr int, stueck int);

insert into lagerbuchung values (10, -5);
insert into lagerbuchung values (10, 100);
```

Then I have created an object type with two columns and table type made of that object:

```
create type test_type is object (lagernummer2 varchar2(500), summe2 varchar2(500));
create type test_tab is table of test_type;
```

After that I have created your function:

```
create or replace function test_cursor (lagernummer in int)
return test_tab
is
   v_test_tab test_tab := test_tab();
   n integer := 0;

   summe               number := 0;
   kapazitätsgränze    number;
begin

   SELECT l.stueckkap
   INTO kapazitätsgränze
   FROM lager l
   WHERE lagernummer = l.lnr;
   
   FOR v_rec IN (SELECT *
                 FROM lagerbuchung l2
                 WHERE l2.lnr = lagernummer)
   LOOP
   
       summe := summe + v_rec.stueck;
       IF (summe > kapazitätsgränze) then
           v_test_tab.extend;
           n := n + 1;
           v_test_tab(n) := test_type('Überfüllter Lagerstand' || ' ' || lagernummer, summe);
       else
           v_test_tab.extend;
           n := n + 1;
           v_test_tab(n) := test_type('Negativer Lagerstand' || ' ' || lagernummer, '<html><font size="5" color="red">' || summe);
       end if;
       
   end loop;
   
   return v_test_tab;
end;
/
```

This procedure returns the test_tab type.

Then you call the function ike this:

```
select * 
from table(test_cursor(10));
```

Here is the DEMO:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0b4c389fb61bfba898c72359ec9b9312)

Comment: Is it possible to implement it in ´´´IF´´´ or I need extra select like shown

Comment: I mean how would I output summe as a red textcolor